# Existing column value of a table to be set to NULL on button click using IronPython - Spotfire

Tags: ironpython, spotfire

On **click of a button**, the existing column value should be **set to NULL**. To be implemented using **IronPython script** - SPOTFIRE........

Below is the example given for better understanding of my requirement.

**Example:**

[image]

Comment: If anybody has tried this please share the code snippet...

Comment: @LaxmiAcharya- As sophros commented above, post your code so that someone from SO community could suggest changes to your code to make it work.

Comment: `value = Document.Properties['NA']
tbl_target = Document.Data.Tables['student']
target_col = tbl_target.Columns.Item['marks']
target_col.Properties.SetProperty('Expression', value)`

Comment: This above code works fine if the columnType is Calculated Column.... But in my case columntype is **Imported**.....Please do help with this one!!!

Comment: @LaxmiAcharya can you add a calculated column that is simply equal to the one you want set to NULL?

Answer (score 1):

an Imported column means that the data lives outside of Spotfire, so of course you cannot change it; Spotfire does not support "writing" data.

you could create the *illusion* that the values are null by using a calculated column with something like `if(${MyDocumentProperty} = "nullify", "NULL", [Marks]`. but again, it is not possible to change the underlying data.